# Upload file Amazon S3 return The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

I try upload file in amazon s3, but  always return this message.

My code:

```
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config()
{
    ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
    CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP,
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.SAEast1
};

using (AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(KEY_S3, PASSWORD, S3Config))
{

    string pathInS3 = folder + "/" + fileName;
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();

    request.WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME);
    request.WithKey(pathInS3); 
    request.WithInputStream(memoryStreamFile);
    request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite;

    client.PutObject(request);

}
```

I had use lock in request and client but do not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the memoryStreamFile, please do double check trying to read the content of your memorystreamFile.So another way to upload files to AmazonS3 with C# is the following:

```
            AmazonS3Config cfg = new AmazonS3Config();
            cfg.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;// region endpoint
            string bucketName = "your bucket";
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("your access key", "your secret key", cfg);            
            string dataString ="your data ";
            MemoryStream data = new System.IO.MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString));
            TransferUtility t = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
            t.Upload(data, bucketName, "testUploadFromTransferUtility.txt");
```